# Saving various files in different folders into one single folder using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a 3 folders here with 3 files.

[image]

Within each there is a csv file, I want to save them all into a destination folder without having to open each folder and drag and drop the file into the destination folder.

I attempted this.

```
$destination = "C:\Desktop\Test"
$sourcefiles = get-childitem -recurse
    
foreach ($file in $sourcefiles)
{
    Copy-Item $file.FullName -Destination "$destination\$file.Name"
}
```

When I do that, I get the folders copied, which is really cool, but no file.

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Looking for something like this...FileA resides in TestA, FileB resides in TestB.. I have several hundred of these and I have to save them into a backup location

[image]

Comment: You should call `get-childitem -file -recurse` to only retrieve files and not directories too.

Comment: destination should be `"$destination\$($file.Name)"` the double quotes are not allowing you to expand the value of the `Name` property (hence the use of `$( )`)

Comment: ...or just `$destination` as you don't change the filename. In this case make sure that destination directory exists before copying, otherwise it would create a file with this name.

Comment: Thank you, I must be doing something wrong still. After I remove the -recurse and added the $() I get folders but nothing in it. I just want to save files into a destination folder

Comment: Keep the `-recurse`, do it exactly as I wrote in my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to copy the folders and it's contents to a new destination, so, simply target the folders and then use [`Copy-Item -Recurse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.2#example-2-copy-directory-contents-to-an-existing-directory):

```sh
Get-ChildItem path\to\testfolders -Directory | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\Desktop\Test" -Recurse
```

Comment: amazing. I made a tweak to filter for just csv files and it worked.